# Imageview darg and drop into recylerview Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I want to have a view inside a scrollable layout (Recyclerview with GridlayoutManager) with tiles (Views) in it. Dragging and dropping an item to RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this for drag and drop in recycler view.
https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd#.yt2erbko9

To know about drop event check this [issue](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/issues/11).

**Update**

For external views drag event check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575100/android-recyclerview-drag-and-drop-external-view-and-auto-scroll).

Comment: I need to drag a image view into recylerview